# CouchDB Validation against Data in other documents

Tags: couchdb

I have a question about update validations in CouchDB. I want to add a validation that will allow to enter values in a special field only if there ist another document containing that String. Let me give an example:

I have a few document of type `City`. The documents contain just the type and a name. There are no validations required for this type. I have another type `Person`. Among other data there is a field `city`, as you might expect, that field should be validated to only contain cities which are already present in the other type.

From the arguments of the validate function I see no possibility to find the other docs, an older question here at stackoverflow seems to suggest that this is not possible, but I'm not sure if that's still valid. Also, might the update validation be the wrong place to check for that or is there a workaround?

Thanks to all!

Chris

Comment: I'm looking for this exact same thing! I can't believe that there have been no answers or comments